# How can I paste ranges using variable references?

Tags: excel, vba, copy, range, paste

I am attempting to paste several ranges from one workbook to another using variables as the references. I was successful in running this for individual cells, but I think my syntax is wrong now that I am trying ranges. I am fairly new to VBA, please let me know your thoughts if this is an easy catch for you. Thanks!

```
Sub pasteRanges()

     x1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(19, 14).value
     x2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(23, 14).value
     x3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(26, 14).value
     x4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(30, 14).value
     x5 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(33, 14).value
     x6 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(34, 14).value
     x7 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(38, 14).value
     x8 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(42, 14).value
     x9 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(44, 14).value
     x10 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(57, 14).value

     y = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(19, 15).value

     Z = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(19, 16).value


     rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x1, y), .Cells(x2, y)")
     rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x3, y), .Cells(x4, y)")
     rng3 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x5, y), .Cells(x6, y)")
     rng4 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x1, Z), .Cells(x2, Z)")
     rng5 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x3, Z), .Cells(x4, Z)")
     rng6 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x5, Z), .Cells(x6, Z)")
     rng7 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x7, Z), .Cells(x8, Z)")
     rng8 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(".Cells(x9, Z), .Cells(x10, Z)")


     Workbooks.Open ("Book2")

        
        
     Application.Workbooks("Book2.xls,").Worksheets("Destination").Range("rng1") _
    = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("H19:H23")

 End Sub
```

Comment: when you put something between `" "` vba sees a string. All variables go without them, but you need to declare every single variable, use `Option Explicit` on top of your module to force yourself declaring all variables in play. You are using x1,2... as values then using them to tell the row for the ranges... There are better ways to do this if you elaborate a bit more your problem.

Comment: With respect, I think your code needs a lot of work. Can you add a sentence or two to explain what exactly you are trying to do here? Why do you need to move data from one workbook to another in this way? What data is it? If you can add images as well, that will probably help.